# Why is my app being referenced twice when using alias in the console?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

in `iex -S mix` when I do alias `MyApp.Services.DoStuff`

I see a response of `MyApp.MyApp.Services.DoStuff`

Which doesn't seem to let me use my module in the console.

My module is defined in `lib/myapp/services/dostuff.ex`

`defmodule MyApp.Services.DoStuff do ...`

Comment: Are you able to call `MyApp.Services.DoStuff.some_function` (for some valid function name)? And what does `DoStuff.some_function` (for the same function name) say after doing the `alias`?

Comment: @Dogbert If I do `MyApp.Services.DoStuff.some_function` before I use alias I get `MyApp.MyApp.Services.DoStuff` is undefined module not available. If I then use alias, I get the same error

Comment: Just read the part about Elixir alias and it looks like `alias Elixir.MyApp.Services.DoStuff` will allow me to use my functions in that module, but I'm confused why I need to namespace with Elixir when the alias without a namespace seems to think I want to import `MyApp.MyApp.Services.DoStuff`?

Comment: Do you have anything in `.iex.exs`? Are you running any code before the `alias` in `iex`? Can you try replicating this in a brand new mix project? It's a little hard to debug like this without having a reproducible case locally.

Comment: @Dogbert ahhhh ok looks like I accidentally added alias MyApp.MyApp in my `.iex.exs` Didn't even realize it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments Dogbert led me to realize that I had accidentally aliased MyApp.MyApp in my `.iex.exs` file. Must have been due to a lot of copy pasting...